# Getting predicted labels outside of the expected range (PyTorch Graph Convolutional Networks)

Tags: pytorch, neural-network, conv-neural-network, pytorch-geometric, graph-neural-network

I am trying to use a GCN to classify functions from Solidity smart contracts into their respective vulnerability if they posses one. I am trying to follow a guide from this link: [https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/get_started/introduction.html](https://stackoverflow.com).

The issue is, I keep receiving predicted labels that are outside of the expected range. It should be 0-5, but I am getting numbers that is way over that, like 159,35,and 59 just to name a few.

My model is declared as follows

```
class GCNModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, output_dim):
        super(GCNModel, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = GCNConv(input_dim, 16)
        self.conv2 = GCNConv(16, output_dim)
        self.linear = nn.Linear(output_dim, output_dim)  # Add a linear layer

    def forward(self, x, edge_index):
        x = self.conv1(x, edge_index)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = F.dropout(x, training=self.training)
        x = self.conv2(x, edge_index)
        return F.log_softmax(x, dim=1)
```

This is the training & validation portion of my code in my main method.

```
    random.seed(42)  # Set a seed for reproducibility
    input_dim = 5  # Dimensionality of node features
    output_dim = 6  # Number of output classes (vulnerability labels)
    model = GCNModel(input_dim, output_dim)

    # Set up training parameters
    lr = 0.001  # Learning rate
    num_epochs = 20

    # Define the loss function and optimizer
    loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=lr)
    best_val_accuracy = 0.0
    best_model = None

    # Create an instance of ASTDataset
    ast_dataset = ASTDataset(tasks, is_training=True)

    # Create a DataLoader with the IterableDataset
    dataloader = DataLoader(ast_dataset, num_workers=0)

    # Train the model
    print("Training model...")
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        model.train()
        epoch_loss = 0.0
        train_correct = 0
        train_total = 0
        train_graphs = 0
        val_correct = 0  # Move outside the loop
        val_total = 0  # Move outside the loop

        for i, data_list in enumerate(dataloader):
            if i <= training_count:
                for data in data_list:
                    x, edge_index, y = data.x, data.edge_index, data.y
                    optimizer.zero_grad()
                    # Forward pass
                    y_pred = model(x, edge_index)
                    # Compute the loss
                    # Compute the loss
                    y_pred = y_pred.view(y.size(0), -1)  # Reshape y_pred to match the shape of y
                    loss = F.nll_loss(y_pred, y)
                    # Backward pass and optimization step
                    loss.backward()
                    optimizer.step()
                    epoch_loss += loss.item() * len(data)
                    _, predicted_label = torch.max(y_pred, 1)
                    train_correct += (predicted_label == y).sum().item()
                    train_total += len(y)
                    train_graphs += 1
                    epoch_loss /= train_graphs
                    train_accuracy = train_correct / train_total
            else:
                for data in data_list:
                    x, edge_index, y = data.x, data.edge_index, data.y
                    # Evaluation on the validation set
                    model.eval()

                    print(data)
                    y_pred = model(x, edge_index)
                    y_pred = y_pred.view(y.size(0), -1)  # Reshape y_pred to

                    _, predicted_label = torch.max(y_pred, 1)
                    val_correct += (predicted_label == y).sum().item()
                    val_total += len(y)
                        
                    val_accuracy = val_correct / val_total

        # Check if the current model has the highest validation accuracy
        if val_accuracy > best_val_accuracy:
            best_val_accuracy = val_accuracy
            best_model = model.state_dict()  # Save the state of the model
        print(f"Epoch {epoch + 1}/{num_epochs}, Loss: {epoch_loss:.4f}, Training Accuracy: {train_accuracy:.4f}, Validation Accuracy: {val_accuracy:.4f}")
```

I am fairly certain there is nothing wrong with my data either. An example of a "data" object in the "data_list" is shown below:

```
DataBatch(x=[40, 5], edge_index=[2, 78], y=[1], batch=[40], ptr=[2])
```

Where x is a tensor of 40 vectors of length 5, which are some features that I have extracted. I am also currently using an "IterableDataset" to send batches into my model to prevent my program from using up too much memory by storing the entire data at once. I am not sure if this is related, but I can post the code if anyone of you thinks it is necessary to solve this.

I tried playing around with the softmax and log.softmax function as suggested by ChatGPT and spent many hours trying to ensure my data is correct, but I am still very confused as to why this is happening.

Thank you for reading, and let me know if there's any other info I can provide! Any help would be greatly appreciated.